# MongoDB group and sort documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to sort the data based on the max. value from the group.
The data:

```
> db.test.find({})
{"a" : 1, "d" : 10 }
{"a" : 1, "d" : 1 }
{"a" : 2, "d" : 50 } // changed, it was initially ({"a" : 2, "d" : 20 })
{"a" : 2, "d" : 2 }
{"a" : 3, "d" : 30 }
{"a" : 3, "d" : 4 }
{"a" : 1, "d" : 10 }
```

Result:

a: 2, d: 50 |
a: 2: d: 2 |
a: 3, d: 30 |
a: 3, d: 4 |
a: 1, d: 10 |
a: 1, d: 10 |
a: 1, d 1

SQL equivalent:

```
create table test(a integer, d integer);
insert into test 
select 3,  30 union all
select 3,  4 union all
select 2,  20 union all
select 2,  2 union all
select 1, 10 union all
select 1,  10 union all
select 1, 1;

select a, d, max(d) over (partition by a) as max_in_group
from test
order by 3 desc, 2 desc;
```

or

```
select *
from test t
inner join 
(
select a, max ( d ) as max_d
from test
group by a
)X on t.a = x.a
order by max_d desc, d desc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/):

```js
db.coll.aggregate(
  {$sort: {d: -1}},
  {$group: {_id: "$a", d: {$push: "$d"}, max: {$max: "$d"}}},
  {$sort: {max: -1}},
  {$unwind: "$d"},
  {$project: {a: "$_id", d: 1, _id: false}}
);
```

result:

```js
{ "d" : 30, "a" : 3 }
{ "d" : 4,  "a" : 3 }
{ "d" : 20, "a" : 2 }
{ "d" : 2,  "a" : 2 }
{ "d" : 10, "a" : 1 }
{ "d" : 10, "a" : 1 }
{ "d" : 1,  "a" : 1 }
```

P.S.: you can remove first pipeline stage `{$sort: {d: -1}}` if you don't care of order inside group; you'll get next result:

```js
{ "d" : 30, "a" : 3 }
{ "d" : 4,  "a" : 3 }
{ "d" : 20, "a" : 2 }
{ "d" : 2,  "a" : 2 }
{ "d" : 10, "a" : 1 } 
{ "d" : 1,  "a" : 1 } // <--   not
{ "d" : 10, "a" : 1 } // <-- ordered
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nice one!

Comment: I do care. The given expression is suppose to group the messages by user and I have to sort each group by data + paging. Thanks again.

Comment: @DraganS cast an index on field `d`, so mongo won't do first heavy stage everytime